# How to mock an object returned by a mocked object?

Tags: python, unit-testing, mocking

I don't quite have the hang of Python mocks.

Clearly I don't want my test code to call the actual method`requests.post()` in the following method, so I want to to mock its behavior instead:

```
def try_post(self, url, body):
    r = requests.post(url, data=body)
    msg = str(r.status_code) + " " + r.content + "\n"
    if r.status_code >= 300:
        sys.stderr.write("Error: POST returned " + msg)
```

My question: How do I mock the object returned by `requests.post()`, i.e. the response object?

For example, I'd like to write one test where r.status_code is 200 and another where r.status_code is 300 so I can test the conditional logic.  Also, I'd need to mock r.content to return some string.

My non-working code follows:

```
from monitor_writer import MonitorWriter
import mock
import unittest

class TestMonitorWriter(unittest.TestCase): 

    @mock.patch('monitor_writer.requests')
    def test_conforming_write(self, mock_requests):
        xml_frag = """
<InstantaneousDemand>
</InstantaneousDemand>
"""
        mock_requests.status_code.return_value = 200
        mock_requests.content.return_value = "OK"

        writer = MonitorWriter()
        writer.update(xml_frag)
        self.assertTrue(mock_requests.post.called, "Failed to call requests.post")
```

This test fails with `TypeError: expected a character buffer object` because r.status_code and r.content evaluate to mock.MagicMock objects, not strings, and the try_post() method is attempting to catenate them.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want to mock `requests.post` directly, rather than the entire `requests` module:

```
class TestMonitorWriter(unittest.TestCase): 

    @mock.patch('monitor_writer.requests.post')
    def test_conforming_write(self, mock_post):
        xml_frag = """
<InstantaneousDemand>
</InstantaneousDemand>
"""
        response = mock.MagicMock()
        response.status_code = 200
        respone.content = "OK"
        mock_post.return_value = response

        writer = MonitorWriter()
        writer.update(xml_frag)
        self.assertTrue(mock_post.called, "Failed to call requests.post")
```

Once we've mocked the function you're actually calling, we create a mock response object,  set `status_code` and `content` on the mocked response to the desired values, and finally assign the mocked response to the `return_value` of our mocked `post` function.

Comment: Now that I see it, that makes so much sense.  And it works.  Thank you for setting me straight.  (FWIW, I could not find this in several of the tutorials & quick starts that I read.)